# Recovering table data from table layer of ArcGIS.com

Tags: arcgis-online, table

I am a researcher tracking Florida's COVID-19 tests that they report on the coronavirus dashboard here: https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/96dd742462124fa0b38ddedb9b25e429

They used to have a data navigator I could access and get the data from, but they disabled it today. I can view the table of test data in the ArcGIS viewer, but cannot figure out if I can extract/download it. I need it because it is the only place they report the age and sex breakdown of who gets tested by county.

Is there any way for me to get this data from them or is my research basically ruined?

I would normally try to do this by myself, but I don't have the luxury of time and I don't want to compromise my research by a multi-day gap.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, I suggest getting in contact with the creators of the dashboard. There may be reasons why they removed the data, e.g. it may not be reliable.  The [Florida COVID-19 Confirmed Cases](https://fdoh.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d0de33f260d444c852a615dc7837c86) page has the following statement with a link to email.

> For issues or problems with the map or dashboard, please email the
>   DOH-GIS Office with information about the error or problem.

Comment: If you scroll down on that page far enough, it explains how you can access the data, via hosted services: `The Florida Department of Health publishes six feature services that are available for public use. These layers are the only official and authoritative data counts published by the Department of Health through ArcGIS Online.`

Comment: If your need is to download this data, both ArcGIS Pro and to my understanding, QGIS can pull in these hosted services. Its just a matter of doing an export to CSV or whatever format you require. Sure, it would be nice if they just stood up an Open Data site that wraps these services and gives a CSV export... but it doesnt look like that's out there.